# L298 H-bridge: there is voltage, but it disappears once motor is connected

Tags: arduino, dc-motor, h-bridge, l298

I'm trying to drive a DC motor in different directions with the help of L298 H-bridge (multiwatt vertical package) and an Arduino. I can measure how voltage changes from -5V to +5V, give or take, between theoutput pins as the Arduino pins are switched in turn, but once I plug in the motor the voltage between the H-bridge outputs drops to zero. The motor isn't broken, I've checked that. When I connect the H-bridge output with a resistor and an LED it works with 5-ish V potential between the H-bridge outputs.

[image]

Comment: What motor is it? Is there any datasheet or at least a model number? Where do you take the 6V supply voltage from? Are you sure it can handle the current demand of the motor? One final thing: CURRENT SENSE pins are not meant to be left floating. If there's no need to sense/control the motor current then tie that pin to ground. See my answer [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/594365/l298n-constant-output-power/594368#594368) for details about current sense pin.

Comment: [Problems with L293, L298 and SN754410 H-bridge drivers on a low voltage supply](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/108686/problems-with-l293-l298-and-sn754410-h-bridge-drivers-on-a-low-voltage-supply)

Comment: @RohatKılıç It's a small toy collector motor, not sure about the part number, it's about 10 Ohms and it needs between 3 and 6 V . 6V is taken from an AC/DC converter.

Comment: @RohatKılıç indeed, the problem was with the floating current sensing pins.

Comment: Please check if your power supply is sufficient for powering up the L298 and the motors. Also please check if there is any short circuit.  You can also follow this Arduino tutorial for cross-checking: https://www.theengineeringprojects.com/2017/07/introduction-to-l298.html